# Pagination in virtuemart joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

joomla version 2.5

When the "disable SEO" option  is unchecked the virtuemart product is going under 404 error, So thats must to be checked the "disable SEO" option of virtuemart,

But when it is disabled the pagination doesnt work ...

when checked its taking a url

("http://www.example.com/component/virtuemart/view/category/virtuemart_category_id/9/start/20")

and when unchecked taking a another url

("http://www.example.com/component/virtuemart/9/children-s-books/results,21-20")

can any one give me a solution for this..

Comment: Please check if virtuemart is updated and try to disable template override to see if the problem is getting fixed.